Hot wires connected together and the neutrals go to the switch
I was looking to replace this old box and the switches. I noticed something I had never seen before, the hot wires (black) are connected together in a nut whereas the neutral (white) wires are connected to switches. I checked with my tester and indeed the black wires are hot. The switch does turn the light on/off, but even when off the wire that goes from the outlet to the light still has power despite the switch being off, it makes sense considering the black wires aren't controlled by the switch. Should I do the reverse and connect the white wires together and the black wires to the switch as found in normal installations?


the always hot comes from the ceiling

More photos needed.  We can only see one wire clearly in that photo, which is not enough to make a safe guess.

See also https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/156756/when-wiring-a-switch-should-i-break-the-neutral-or-power-wire and https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/55719/is-switching-the-neutral-ok

Are you confident the wire's colours are correct ?

Yes. Change the wiring so that the switch is controlling the hot wire to the light.
While the current setup works fine from an electricity viewpoint, it can give a nasty surprise if someone is not aware that the hot remains live when replacing the light bulb, even with the switch off.

It is also now against code (see NEC 404.2(B) - "grounded conductor" means the neutral wire in this context; I don't know exactly when that change was made, but it was at least several decades ago).

But many houses/flats are older than that. We can expect quite big portion of those are having the circuits untouched since the construction.
